# C++ Inventario de armas

Tags: c++, revisión-de-código, c++11

estoy estudiando desarrollo de videojuegos haciendo uso de C++.
Para mi proyecto, tengo pensado crear un mini-juego FPS con armas.
Posteo aquí con el fin de que me ayuden un poco a pensar como serian las clases encargadas de gestionar el inventario.

Me gustaría que en mi juego haya varios tipos de armas, cada tipo asociado a un ".mesh" que son los modelos 3D, ademas cada arma tenga una potencia, cadencia y cantidad de balas del cargador distintas.

Me gustaría que mientras vaya avanzando de nivel, se le vayan asignado diferentes armas a su inventario.

Tengo algo de código del curso:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;


template<class T>
T* deleter(T* x) {
  delete x;
  return 0;
}

class Weapon {
  int ammo;

protected:
  virtual int power(void) const = 0;
  virtual int max_ammo(void) const = 0;

public:
  Weapon(int ammo=0) : ammo(ammo) { }

  void shoot(void) {
    if (ammo > 0) ammo--;
  }

  bool is_empty(void) {
    return ammo == 0;
  }

  int get_ammo(void) {
    return ammo;
  }

  void add_ammo(int amount) {
    ammo = min(ammo + amount, max_ammo());
  }

  bool same_weapon_as(Weapon* other) {
    return typeid(*this) == typeid(*other);
  }
};


class Pistol : public Weapon {
  virtual int power(void) const    { return 1; };
  virtual int max_ammo(void) const { return 50; };

    public:
      Pistol(int ammo=0) : Weapon(ammo) {}
    };

class Inventory : public vector<Weapon*> {
public:
  typedef typename Inventory::const_iterator WeaponIter;
  typedef vector<Weapon*> WeaponVector;
  class WeaponNotFound {};
  ~Inventory();

  void add(Weapon* weapon) {
    auto it = find_if(begin(), end(),
              bind(&Weapon::same_weapon_as, _1, weapon));

    if (it != end()) {
      (*it)->add_ammo(weapon);
      delete weapon;
      return;
    }

    push_back(weapon);
  }

  WeaponVector weapons_with_ammo(void) {
    WeaponVector retval;

    remove_copy_if(begin(), end(), back_inserter(retval),
           bind(&Weapon::is_empty, _1));

    if (retval.begin() == retval.end())
      throw Inventory::WeaponNotFound();

    return retval;
  }

  Weapon* more_powerful_weapon(void) {
    WeaponVector weapons = weapons_with_ammo();

    sort(weapons.begin(), weapons.end(),
         bind(&Weapon::less_powerful_than, _1, _2));

    return *(weapons.end()-1);
  }
};

Inventory::~Inventory() {
  transform(begin(), end(), begin(), deleter<Weapon>);
  clear();
}
```

Que piensan?

Comment: Es muy difícil entender lo que necesitas sin más detalle... sólo con conjeturas llenaría varias páginas ¿No podrías concretar un poco más?

Comment: @pap acabo de poner mas detalles.

Comment: Sigue siendo algo muy amplio, por lo que te puedo responder de manera amplia: No mezcles lógica y visualización, las características del arma (potencia, cadencia y tamaño del cargador) no tienen que ver con su representación visual (mesh).

Comment: Pero en algún lugar tiene que estar guardada esa relación es decir, cuando si selecciono la pistola, tengo que cargar pistola.mesh

Comment: Efectivamente, si usas el arma `1` usa el mesh `1`, sabes que hay una relación índice-entidad, pero no guardas en la clase lógica los datos visuales.

Comment: Interesante, yo lo guardaba jaja! En fin, lo que yo buscaba con esta respuesta es que tomaran mi código y le aplicaran mejoras, de como pensaban ustedes que queda mejor implementarlo

Comment: para los que la votan por cerrar, me pregunto, si esta pregunta no entraria dentro de la categoria -> `revision-de-codigo` aceptada aqui -> https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio Saludos

Comment: No me termina de quedar clara la pregunta, de hecho, no hay pregunta a simple vista: has descrito qué es lo que quieres hacer en el juego, pero no cuál es el problema que estás teniendo.